# How do you disconnect a Canon 70D from the EOS app on an iPhone?

Tags: canon, iphone, canon-70d

I recently downloaded the EOS app for iPhone to try it out. I didn't really like it so how do I disconnect my 70D camera safely from my iPhone?

Comment: Note, the "EOS Remote" app is a legacy app, you should be using the "Camera Connect" app if you aren't already.

Answer (score 4):

No harm will come to either the camera or the phone by disconnecting in any way, so just do whatever's easiest. Any of these will work:

- The app has a button to disconnect.
- Turn off the WiFi connection on the camera.
- Kill the app on the phone. (Press the home button twice and then swipe up on the image of the EOS app's screen.)
- Switch the WiFi network on the phone or turn off WiFI.